# Optimal bitshift multiplication

Tags: algorithm, optimization, bit-shift, multiplication

Multiplication by a constant can be replaced by left shifts, additions and subtractions:

```
int multiply10(int x){
    return (x<<3)+(x<<1);
}

int multiply31(int x){
    return (x<<5)-x;
}
```

So I thought, why not extend this to larger numbers? But a simple sum is very slow:

```
int multiply52429(int x){
    return (x<<15)+(x<<14)+(x<<11)+(x<<10)+(x<<7)+(x<<6)+(x<<3)+(x<<2)+x;
}
```

so we make some variables:

```
int multiply52429(int x){
    int y = (x<<1)+x;
    y = (y<<4)+y;
    y = (y<<8)+y;
    return (y<<2)+x;
}
```

So now we ask, how to generate code for such a function that is optimal?*

Only additions, subtractions and left shift by constant will be counted towards the total, all with a "cost" of 1, everything else is free.

*AST, assembly, whatever, any format that can be converted is fine. Here what matters is the optimal multiplication algorithm, not the code formatting.

Some examples which are probably near optimal:

```
int multiply1671523a(int x){
    int x3 = (x<<1)+x;
    int x99 = (x3<<5)+x3;
    return (x99<<15)-(x3<<19)+(x<<8)+x99;
}

int multiply1671523b(int x){
    int x3 = (x<<1)+x;
    int x51 = (x3<<4)+x3;
    return (x51<<15)+(x<<8)+(x3<<4)+x51;
}

int multiply1671523c(int x){
    int x3 = (x<<1)+x;
    return (x3<<19)+(x3<<15)+(x<<8)+(x3<<5)+x3;
}

int multiply220374293(int x){
    int x5 = (x<<2)+x;
    int x21 = (x5<<2)+x;
    int x105 = (x21<<2)+x21;
    return (x105<<21)+(x21<<13)+(x5<<8)+x21;
}
```

Note the reuse in the last example.

---

This has no practical use (multiplication is always faster, and if it's somehow slower the compiler will take care of it), but I thought it was a neat problem and was curious. What kind of algorithm would solve it, and with what time complexity?

Comment: There's a potentially large win if you allow subtraction as well; This would be called [Booth encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Booth%27s_multiplication_algorithm).

Comment: Side note: everywhere you have `int` here, you really mean `unsigned int`.

Comment: (GCC does a pretty good job *for three-address machines*. There are "hard" cases - try 171, 173 & 203.)

Comment: My personal opinion is that this is a very hard problem. It is most reminiscent to me of trying to invert an [ARX (Add-Rotate-XOR) cryptographical block cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher#ARX_add-rotate-xor), and of course that's meant to be impractical.